# How do i check for incorrect decimal format?

Tags: python, decimal

I am putting together an error log that will be integrated into a  GUI (General User Interface). The GUI allows requires the user to enter a decimal number that is less than 5 but more than 0, has no more than 2 decimal places and has only 1 decimal point. Checking value is less than 5 more than 0 is no problem, but how do i check that the other 2 points (must have 1 decimal point no more no less and must have 2 decimal places no more no less)

Additionally i will likely result in having 10-20 if statements any recommendations on a better format than using many if statements would be appreciated.

example code that i'm working with is below:

```
test1 = 0.65  # Test 1
test2 = 0.71  # Test 2
test3 = 0.12  # Test 3

tests =[test1,test2,test3]  #Create Test Array

tests.sort() # Sort Test array from largest to smalest so i can check that the test values are within max range of 0.1
print(tests)  #Print Array
lowtest = tests[0]  #set Low value
hightest = tests[2] # Set High Value
testvariance = hightest-lowtest # Check Variance
testvariance = round(testvariance,2)  # variance to 2 decimal places
print(testvariance) # variance

if test1 == 0:  #Check Value is entered as default value is 0
    print("Test 1 Missing")
elif test2 == 0: #Check Value is entered as default value is 0
    print("Test 2 Missing")
elif test3 == 0: #Check Value is entered as default value is 0
    print("Test 3 Missing")    
elif testvariance >=.1: # Check values are within range tolerance of 0.1
    print("Outside of test range tollerance")
elif testvariance <=.1  and testvariance>=0:
    print("Within Test Range") 
else:
    print("Error Unknown State")
```

Comment: What is the your goal behind ensuring that no more than 2 decimal digits are entered? Can you not just convert the input value to a float using `float(value)`?

Comment: The goal is to get a certain degree of accuracy no less, no more (using equipment which requires specialized inputs). Should user enter an invalid value i would ideally like to stop it at the GUI level. I can convert it to a float though i don't see how that would help me getting to where i want to go.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression to tackle all these challenges simultaneously (assuming you are enforcing that two values come after the decimal, and that the user input is initially a string):

```py
import re

pattern = re.compile(r"^[0-4]\.\d{2}$")
```

Demonstration:

```py
In [2]: while True:
   ...:     print(pattern.findall(input()))
   ...:     print()
   ...:
1.12
['1.12']

0.52
['0.52']

0.0.0.0.
[]

5.00
[]

4.99
['4.99']

3.14
['3.14']

hello
[]

938176
[]

AU)(*E
[]

...3.14
[]
```

Note that you'll need to convert the values to float yourself.

If you want to allow for *up to* two decimal places to be included:

```py
pattern = re.compile(r"^[0-4]\.\d{1,2}$")
```

Comment: Thanks, I've never seen this method before so I'll have a read and a play and get back to you on this. Thanks